# How do I make an image in PDF open its link in new pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I am embedding a PDF in an HTML. There are some images with links in PDF. I want to make those link open in a pop-up window/ new window rather than a new/ the same tab on click.

Comment: You could have googled this very easily, add target="_blank" have a read of the attribute [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: I have already tried this, sir. It opens the link in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide a link on PDF in such a way that the link which is to be opened in pop-up should be a parameter. Write a jquery/js script to access that param and open a pop-up window or boostrap modal to show the link in it. I hope this helps.

Comment: like `https://www.some-site.com/some?link=somelink` 
mind you page will be refreshed everytime you click a link.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in JS/jQuery if non of the target attributes work for you

```
   return function(el) {
        el.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var i = $(this).attr('class');
          var u = this.href;
          var c = {h:370, w:550};
          var xPos = ($(window).width()-c.w)/2;
          var n = window.open(u,i,'height='+c.h+',width='+c.w+',left='+xPos+',top=60,screenX='+xPos+',screenY=60');
          if (window.focus) { n.focus(); }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML5 Spec:

> A valid browsing context name is any string with at least one
>   character that does not start with a U+005F LOW LINE character. (Names
>   starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)
>
> A valid browsing context name or keyword is any string that is either
>   a valid browsing context name or that is an ASCII case-insensitive
>   match for one of: _blank, _self, _parent, or _top." - Source

So using

```
target="_blank"
```

Should help you.